# Can we get the integration user details using Rest API

Tags: rest-api

I found this blog https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2018/the-value-of-having-a-dedicated-salesforce-integration-user by using this we can create an Integration User the user is an remote user(no human is access it) the user can manage the all the integrations related to the organizations.in my integration i want this Integration user credentials instead of typing the username and password of this integration user.I want to fetch this Integration user details by using Rest API can anyone help me is it possible or not.

Comment: [Hi is there any Rest api to get the salesforce Integration user details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342836/hi-is-there-any-rest-api-to-get-the-salesforce-integration-user-details). If your question has been closed, please do not create a new identical one. You should edit the original question.

Comment: i deleted that one and this is the new one

Comment: You've copy-pasted it, so nothing has changed. If you've followed the received advices, the chances of being answered would have been higher.

Comment: Thank you for your response actually the question is same in the explanation i changed the content that is more clearly about what my requirement is

Comment: @Prasanna Kumar, The blog posted explains importance of having dedicated Integration User,however the question you posted seem to be not exactly related to the context, instead I would suggest, if you can better articulate the requirement without reference to the blog and add steps which you have already performed to achieve it, and if there are any issues with it, there are chances to get right direction for your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question includes a serious misunderstanding of how integrations authenticate and are secured. **Continuing to pursue this line of inquiry instead of learning more about integration security may put your production systems at serious risk.** You need to stop and learn before you continue your work.

---

An integration should never have access to the actual credentials under which it authenticates. However, some legacy integrations do store a username and password and authenticate using SOAP login or the OAuth username-password flow. This is a bad practice. You should **never** implement a new integration that stores raw credentials.

You cannot retrieve a user's credentials via the REST API as this would be incredibly insecure (and require you to have some other credentials just to talk to the REST API). The direct answer to your question is **absolutely not**.

All integrations should be authenticated to Salesforce using OAuth. OAuth provides the integration with an access token and optionally a refresh token. The integration can use these tokens to maintain persistent access to the API *without* storing or retrieving credentials. OAuth authentication using an integration user, a Connected App, and the Web Server or JWT OAuth flow provides your organization with the best security posture, including the ability to use a minimal permissioning model, monitor integration activity, selectively revoke access, and rotate credentials safely.

OAuth is a very large area; you can start learning with [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration).